# Username + Medal in VSCode status bar

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have seen a lot of users with their username and a medal in the status bar of VSCode. What is this about? What plugin is this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems something related to [Live Share](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MS-vsliveshare.vsliveshare). [image]